# Convert jquery to react component or pure javascript

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I’ve the sample working jQuery code for simple To Do List. How can I change this into pure javascript or react js component.

```
<div class="todo-list container">
  <ul class="list-your-todo">
    <li>
      <input type="text" name="name" class="form-control" placeholder="Name" value="" />
      <p class="deleteList">- Delete this</p>
    </li>
  </ul>
  <p class="addList">+ Add another</p>
</div>

$(function(){
  $('.addList').click(function(){
    var $liLength = $(".list-your-todo li").length;
    var list = $('.todo-list').find('.list-your-todo li:first').html();
    $('.todo-list ul').append('<li class="clearfix showIcon">' + list + '</li>');
  });  
  $(document).on('click', '.deleteList', function(){
    $(this).parent('li').remove();
  });
});
```

this is the working demo https://jsfiddle.net/LxyLg8hh/

Comment: Get started with React.js.

Comment: This is a useful tutorial to help get one started with writing their own React.js components: https://medium.freecodecamp.org/how-to-write-your-first-react-js-component-d728d759cabc

Answer (score 1):

Conversion to pure JavaScript is rather straightforward although a bit more verbose and you need to add one more check for element existence that is performed automatically by jQuery.

```js
const addList = document.querySelector('.addList');

addList.addEventListener('click', event => {
  const liLength = document.querySelectorAll('.list-your-todo li').length;
  let list = document.querySelector('.todo-list li');
  list ? list = list.innerHTML : list = undefined;

  const item = document.createElement('li');
  item.className = 'clearfix showIcon';
  item.innerHTML = list;
  document.querySelector('.todo-list ul').appendChild(item);
});

document.body.addEventListener('click', event => {
  if (event.target.className === 'deleteList') {
    event.target.parentNode.remove();
  }
});
```

```css
.todo-list {
  padding: 50px 0px;
  position: relative;
  width: 500px
}
ul {
  list-style: none;
}
li {
  margin-bottom: 40px;
  line-height: 24px
}
input {
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}
.deleteList, .addList {
  cursor: pointer;
  position: absolute;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 20px;
}
.deleteList {
  right: 0;
}
.addList {
  left: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="todo-list container">
  <ul class="list-your-todo">
    <li>
      <input type="text" name="name" class="form-control" placeholder="Name" value="" />
      <p class="deleteList">- Delete this</p>
    </li>
  </ul>
  <p class="addList">+ Add another</p>
</div>
```